# How do I create an alpha mask which is rewritten when added to?

Tags: c#, xna

[image: Overwritten Alpha Mask]

I am trying to create a mist-like effect in an application where a texture (in the example above the white) becomes transparent (showing the black texture below) around sprites with a gradation of density moving away from their centre. However, whenever I add a new circle to the alpha mask it overwrites the previous additions to the mask texture creating the jarring effect pictured above. I have been trying to get new additions to the mask texture to blend nicely with previous additions but I can't work out how to do it.

I've tried doing things like creating a mask for my mask to blend with but it invariably come out showing nothing, or drawing to my alpha mask using my alpha shader fx file (which produces some very strange visual effects)

**How do I blend the additions to alpha mask together so they don't overwrite each other?**

Any help greatly appreciated.

*-------------Code:-------------*

Updating of the alpha mask is done in this method:

```
public void createLightSource(Vector2 RemovePosition, Texture2D circleTexture)
    {

            // Create a render target, which we will draw to instead of the screen
            RenderTarget2D target = new RenderTarget2D(graphics.GraphicsDevice, mainTexture.Width, mainTexture.Height);

            // set the RenderTarget2D as the target for all future Draw calls untill we say otherwise
            graphics.GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(target);

            // start our batch as usual..
            spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, BlendState.AlphaBlend, SamplerState.PointClamp, null, null);

            // start with a transparent canvas
            graphics.GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Transparent);

            // add in the previously drawn dots from the current alpha map.
            spriteBatch.Draw(alphaMask, new Vector2(0, 0), null, Color.White, 0f, Vector2.Zero, 1f, SpriteEffects.None, 1f);

            // add a new dot to the map. 
            play.game.spriteBatch.Draw(circleTexture,
                    new Vector2((float)(RemovePosition.X - mainTexture.x), (float)(RemovePosition.Y - mainTexture.y)),
                    null,
                    Color.White,
                    0f,
                    new Vector2(circleTexture.Width / 2f, circleTexture.Height / 2f),
                    1f,
                    SpriteEffects.None,
                    1f);

            // end the draw call
            spriteBatch.End();

            // start drawing to the screen again
            graphics.GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);

            // set our Texture2D Alpha Mask to equal the current render target (the new mask).
            // RenderTarget2D can be cast to a Texture2D without a problem
            alphaMask = target;
        }
```

Drawing to the main texture is done in this method:

```
public void mainTextureDraw()
        {
            //alpha shader is the fx file (below)
            alphaShader.Parameters["MaskTexture"]
                                .SetValue(alphaMask);
        // start a spritebatch for our effect
        spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, BlendState.AlphaBlend,
            null, null, null, alphaShader);

        play.game.spriteBatch.Draw(mainTexture,
            position,
            null, Color.White, 0f,
            new Vector2(0, 0),
            1f, SpriteEffects.None, 1f);

        spriteBatch.End();
    }
```

And the important method in the fx file:

```
float4 PixelShaderFunction(float2 inCoord: TEXCOORD0) : COLOR
{
    // we retrieve the color in the original texture at 
    // the current coordinate remember that this function 
    // is run on every pixel in our texture.
    float4 color = tex2D(mainTexture, inCoord);

    // Since we are using a black and white mask the black 
    // area will have a value of 0 and the white areas will 
    // have a value of 255. Hence the black areas will subtract
    // nothing from our original color, and the white areas of
    // our mask will subtract all color from the color.
    color.rgba = color.rgba - tex2D(alphaMask, inCoord).r;

    // return the new color of the pixel.
    return color;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure which direction to approach this since I don't know what the actual result is supposed to look like.  Here are a couple examples of what I'm talking about.

https://plus.google.com/photos/117280483756658540406/albums/5903487202722042913?authkey=CK-_kZvo2Iqy9wE

However, I think the best approach is to look at `PixelShaderFunction`.  You've got the existing texture in `color` and you're using the red component of `tex2D()`.  What I'm wondering if it might be a useful approach is to take tex2D().r and see if it's greater than color.r, and if it, then use color's value instead of subtracting tex2D().

Basically, you have a threshold you want to maintain.  You need to test your conditions at the pixel, then make a decision as to how and if you're going to change it.

Comment: This second one: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-jPUqW89ZRk4/Ue1mViaBgTI/AAAAAAAAApA/4JL7-5GDHf8/s400-no/multiply.png is definitely what I am looking for. I've managed to get something approaching that with BlendState.Additive but having tried what you suggested above it just made the whole screen completely white. Could I see the solution to the second state?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/F8DhKZC.png This is what I get with blend state additive, but as you can see there are still coronas of white spreading into the circles of the other.

Comment: Well...  I used Photoshop to make both of those.  The second one used Multiply, which you might be able to pull off with (color1.r * color2.r)/255